# Simple Question about Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, expectation, conditional-expectation

Suppose we have a sequence of (discrete) random variables $X_0, X_1, \dotsc$ over $E$ and $A \subseteq E$. Let $Y$ be some other random variable. Moreover, let $Z$ be a random variable with values in $\{0,1,\dotsc\}$

Is it always true that

$$\mathbb{E}[\sum_{n \geq 0} 1(X_n \in A)]= \sum_{n \geq 0 } \mathbb{P}[X_n \in A] \quad (1)$$

for example using the Monotone Convergence Theorem?

Is it always true that

$$\mathbb{E}[Y \sum_{n \geq 0} 1(X_n \in A)]= \sum_{n \geq 0 } \mathbb{E}[Y \cdot 1(X_n \in A)]\quad (2)$$
for example uing the Montone convergence theorem or do we use boundedness of $Y$?

Is it always true that $$\mathbb{E}[Y \cdot 1(Z < \infty)]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[Y \cdot 1(Z=n)] \quad (3)$$
or is this only valid using Dominated Convergence, when $Y$ is bounded?

For non-negative random variables $U_i \geq 0$ for $i=0,1,\dotsc$ is it always true that 
$$\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} U_i] = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[U_i] \quad (4)$$

by the monotone convergence theorem?
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want $X_n$ in your sums instead of $X_0$. Anyway:

Case 1: Yes, monotone convergence is sufficient to prove it.

Case 2: If $Y$ takes on one sign, or more generally is bounded in one direction or another, then monotone convergence will give you this. In general this could fail. The most general but still practical way to check this that I can think of would be to check whether $Y$ has finite variance and the sum converges in mean square. (In particular the sum converges in mean square if it is bounded a.s., because of monotonicity.) If both of those hold then you get what you want.

Case 3: I think the situation is the same here as in case 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this helps a lot. Of course I mean $X_n$, I have updated the question now. Do you have any idea for (4)? Probably it would work exactly as (1)?

Comment: Yes, it's known as 'Beppo Levi' Theorem

Comment: @user136457 Case 4 is essentially the extension of case 1 from indicator functions to nonnegative random variables. It goes through without a hitch based on the standard simple function approximation argument.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Again a question: Can you tell me then why I cannot apply Monotone convergence theorem to get
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n 1(X_k=...)]=\mathbb{E}[\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n 1(X_k=...)]$ then? Because in our lecture we were only able to apply Fatou's Lemma to it. Is this because of the factor $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: @user136457 You can't use monotone convergence because if the $n$th indicator function term is zero, then the $n$th average is smaller than the $(n-1)$th average, while the reverse happens when the $n$th indicator function is $1$. However, you can apply dominated convergence to that situation, since your function is dominated by the constant function $1$. (Fatou's lemma is often used to prove the dominated convergence theorem.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your explanation why monotone convergence does not work totally makes sense to me, thanks for that. But actually I am a little bit confused because we often used dominated convergence in the lecture and I think our professor explicitly mentioned that none of this works and we only get an inequality using Fatou's Lemma, so this sounds really strange to me. For me, dominated convergence would make sense a lot...

Comment: Let me try to explain why monotone convergence doesn't work more carefully. Consider the equivalent situation where you are dealing with $A_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n B_k$ where $B_k$ are Bernoulli random variables (maybe independent, maybe not). Consider $n=2$. If $B_1=0,B_2=1$, then $A_2=1/2>A_1=0$. On the other hand, if $B_1=1,B_2=0$, then $A_2=1/2<A_1=1$. So $A_n$ is not a monotone sequence. Anyway, in this situation, dominated convergence is applicable as soon as $A_n$ is convergent a.s., since as I said $|A_n| \leq 1$, and $1$ is integrable.